# MEAN : Getting whole HTML page instead of mongodb Data Model

Tags: express, mongoose, mean

I'm using mean and [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular).

Everything works fine, except that the  `app.get('/api/todos/', function(req, res)` in my `server.js` file returns my whole HTML page instead of my todos data from my mongodb database!

I can even see my whole index.html getted into my firebug viewer.

If I change **app.get** by **app.post** in the server.js function, I'm getting the todo data model correctly, and my AngularJS frontend show  the todos data correctly, but I wanna use GET, not POST!

It's like app.get or the AngularJS part `$http.get` doesn't work at all.

Do you have any idea?

The iller is that I'm near sure it was working on another computer, and not behavioring like that!

This is the front end controller, like in the tutorial:

```
var scotchTodo = angular.module('scotchTodo', []);

function mainController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};


    $http.get('/api/todos/')
        .success(function(data) {
              $scope.todos = data;  

             console.log(data); 
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

    // Quand on soumets le formulaire ajouter, transmettre la chose à faire à l'api node
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {}; // Supprimer le contenu du formulaire pour que l'utilisateur puisse en utiliser un autre.
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    // Supprimer une chose à faire après l'avoir vérifié.
    $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

}
```

This is the server.js file, llike in the tutorial :

```
// server.js

// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var morgan = require('morgan');                         // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');                // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override');        // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

// configuration =================

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nod');     // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());

// Le serveur va se mettre à écouter avec cette commande (Taper node server.js dans la ligne de commande windows, sous le bon répertoire) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("L app écoute sur le port 8080 dans les navigateurs");



 // definire le modèle de données qui s'apelle todo qui veut dire "chose à faire" =================
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    text : String
});


// routes ======================================================================

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); //Charge la seule vue, c est angular qui s occupe du routing en front end
});

// api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// obtenir tous les todo
app.get('/api/todos/', function(req, res) {

    // utiliser moongoose pour obtenir tous les todo dans la database
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json(todos); // Retourne tous les todo au format json
    });
});

// Créer un todo et retourner tous les todo après création
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});

// supprimer un todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});
```

And finally the AngularJS template is the same as in the tutorial too

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok !

finally they answered under the tutorial :

I've had to Replace the star '*' by nothing 
It will succeeds

Answer (score 0):

From https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

> **After** our API routes, and **before** the app.listen, add this route:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```